# Not equal function not working in PySpark inner join

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataset, I want to join and find out the **How many data in the df1 don't match any of the data we have in the df2 in PySpark**

I tried this code:

```
join = df1.join(df2, df1.studyid != df2.studyid, how='inner')
```

But this code is not working properly.

Please help me out to solve this problem. For more info ping me in chat.

Thanks

Comment: you have pandas tag and pyspark tag, are you using pandas or pyspark ?

Comment: i removed that tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `leftanti`:

```py
join = df1.join(df2, df1.studyid == df2.studyid, how='leftanti')
```

> An anti join returns values from the left relation that has no match with the right. It is also referred to as a left anti join.

More information: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-join.html